# Pandas TypeError: Transform function invalid for data types on max calculation by group

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror, pandas-groupby

I am switching from R and relatively new to python.

I am trying to accomplish a pretty simple task and get a little more complex later.

I am trying to get the max by group, group being 'symbol' in this case, and create a new column with the max from the 'ClosePrice' column.

I am using groupby and transform:

```
proccessing_data['Max'] = proccessing_data.groupby('Symbol').transform(lambda x: x.ClosePrice.max(), axis =1)
```

and return the following error:

```
TypeError: Transform function invalid for data types
```

my end goal is actually to use functions within transform:

```
proccessing_data['RSI'] = proccessing_data.groupby('Symbol').transform(lambda x: talib.RSI(x["ClosePrice"], timeperiod=14), axis =1)
```

but this returns the same error.

for reference in R I use:

```
proccessing_data$RSI_SMA <- ave(proccessing_data$ClosePrice, proccessing_data$Symbol,
                            FUN = function(x) RSI(x,n = 14, maType = "SMA"))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify which column to operate on the grouped data frame before using `transform`, since each column is passed to `transform` function individually, see [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#groupby-transform), you can't do `x.ClosePrice` in the lambda function; For your case:

```
proccessing_data['Max'] = proccessing_data.groupby('Symbol').ClosePrice.transform('max')
#                       specify the column to transform here ^^^^^^^^^^

proccessing_data['RSI'] = proccessing_data.groupby('Symbol').ClosePrice.transform(lambda x: talib.RSI(x, timeperiod=14))
#                       specify the column to transform here ^^^^^^^^^^
```